# ng-file-upload: how to chunk files for Azure blob storage

Tags: angularjs, html, azure-blob-storage, ng-file-upload

I am working on an Angular application and need to allow users the ability mass upload files to an Azure blob storage container using ng-file-upload and html5.  I reviewed the documentation here: https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload but I am not seeing how to apply chunking to a sas url when I need to append the "comp=block&block=id" parameters on the querystring.

How does the ng-file-upload handle this scenario?  Will I need to modify the existing ng-file-upload to accomodate this scenario?  Is there any callbacks currently exposed through Upload.Upload that would allow me to deal with each chunk individually?

Answer (score 0):

When you chunk  upload your file you use the [PutBlock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd135726.aspx) method.

Each chunk will return an ID 
You save the ID and when you completed uploading all your chunks you call the commit  API [put block list](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179467.aspx) and send all the chunk Ids to azure blob storage

The API will set all your chunks as a singe blob